# Are [MySQL] Calendar Aggregate Functions Deterministic

Tags: mysql, calculated-columns

Within a MySQL Table, I have a field `TransMonth`, note this is an actual date, its name reflects that it is stored as a full (1st of Month) date due to how it's imported.

I'd like to add `TransMonth_YR`, `TransMonth_MNTH` etc using Generated Columns.  But I get a general 'check your SQL' error.

```
...right syntax to use near 'PERSISTENT AFTER `DateUpdated`,
    CHANGE COLUMN `TransMonth_QTR` `TransMonth_QTR'
```

Update Code:

```
ALTER TABLE `tbl_transactions`
    CHANGE COLUMN `TransMonth_YR` `TransMonth_YR` SMALLINT(6) AS (YEAR(TransMonth)) PERSISTENT AFTER `DateUpdated`,
    CHANGE COLUMN `TransMonth_QTR` `TransMonth_QTR` TINYINT(4) AS (QUARTER(TransMonth)) PERSISTENT AFTER `TransMonth_YR`,
    CHANGE COLUMN `TransMonth_MNTH` `TransMonth_MNTH` TINYINT(4) AS (MONTH(TransMonth)) PERSISTENT AFTER `TransMonth_QTR`;
```

I've searched, but can find no examples specific to YEAR(), MONTH() etc, just references to DETERMINISTIC built in functions are ok.

My logic says that if you do YEAR(2018-01-01) it will always come back with 2018, so it should be DETERMINISTIC.

Is my logic sound, am I missing something else that is failing?

EDIT: I've found this code at [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table-generated-columns.html)

ALTER tbl_transactions_to_2018_11
ADD COLUMN TransMonth_YR_B
    SMALLINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (YEAR(TransMonth)) STORED

...but this gets the same check your syntax error.  Has anyone got calculated columns working on MySQL?

Comment: What is this `PERSISTENT AFTER`? Where did you get those keywords from? Can you post the link to the documentation where these keywords are being defined?

Comment: I use the HeidiSQL Application.  I added `QUARTER(TransMonth)` to the `Expression` column and then checked the code it generated.  PERSISTENT I presume results in the value being saved to the table, if not it would be generated each time records are received. AFTER just ensures the position of the column in the table.